# Insert Android SQLIte работает частично

Tags: java, android, база-данных, sqlite

После исправления мой метод работал, но не все. Никакая ошибка нету. Вот мой код:

```
DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, "Samo.db", null, 1);
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists incomes(id integer primary key autoincrement, name integer, price real," +
            "quantity integer, provider integer, waybill integer, date text) ");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists outgoe(id integer primary key autoincrement, name integer, " +
            "quantity integer, recipient integer, date text)");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists goods(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text, unit integer)");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists exist(id integer primary key autoincrement, name integer, quantity)");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists providers(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text)");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists units(id integer primary key autoincrement, unit text)");
    db.execSQL("create table if not exists recipients(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    onCreate(db);
}

void insertToIncomes(String name, String price, String unit, String quantity, String provider, String waybill, String date) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    ContentValues cv3 = new ContentValues();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select id from goods where name like '" + name + "'", null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        cv.put("name", cursor.getInt(0));
    else {
        cv2.put("name", name);
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select id from units where unit like '" + unit + "'", null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            cv2.put("unit", cursor.getInt(0));
        else {
            cv3.put("unit", unit);
            db.insert("units", null, cv3);
            cursor = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from units ", null);
            cv2.put("unit", cursor.getCount());
        }
        db.insert("goods", null, cv2);
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from goods ", null);
        cv.put("name", cursor.getCount());
        cv2.clear();
        cv3.clear();
    }
    cv.put(price, Double.parseDouble(price));
    cv.put("quantity", Integer.parseInt(quantity));
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select id from providers where name like '" + provider + "'", null);
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
        cv.put("provider", cursor.getInt(0));
    else {
        cv2.put("name", name);
        db.insert("provider", null, cv2);
        cursor = db.rawQuery("select count(*) from  providers", null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
            cv.put("provider", cursor.getCount());
    }
    cv.put("waybill", waybill);
    cv.put("date", date);
    db.insert("incomes", null, cv);
    cursor.close();
}
```

Он добавляет строки только в goods и units. Проверил через SQLite Manager

[image: screen]

Answer (score 2):

> Он добавляет строки только в goods и units.

Естественно. У Вас таблица называется `providers`, а Вы добавляете запись в таблицу `provider`, которой не существует.

Попробуйте так:

```
db.insert("providers", null, cv2);
```

> Никакая ошибка нету

В случае ошибки метод `insert` возвращает значение `-1`. Поэтому имеет смысл проверять значение, которое метод возвращает после операции. Например, так:

```
if (db.insert("providers", null, cv2) == -1){
    // Здесь обрабатываем ошибку.
}
```

Comment: Работал для providers но incomes все еще пуста

Comment: Нашел ошибку. Здесь забыл кавычку:
    cv.put(price, Double.parseDouble(price));